# WPF MVVM - Updating UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I populate a a `DataGridControl` from the WPF Extended Toolkit with DataTables populated on user  selection.  When user selection is modified, there is not only a large delay with displaying a DataTable with 200 x 1000 rows, there is a user interaction delay that prevents users from interacting with other controls, even though the population of the DataTable binded to the `DataGridControl` occurs on a separate thread.

How do I remove the delay so that the user may interact with other controls in a View while the DataGridControl is updating?

```cs
    public string ListBoxSelection {
                get { 
                    return listBoxSelection;
                }
                set {
                    listBoxSelection = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ListBoxSelection"); //  DataGridSelection

                    BackgroundWorker threadPreviewLoader = new BackgroundWorker();
                    threadPreviewLoader.DoWork += (LoadDataGridPreview); 
                    threadPreviewLoader.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }

    private DataTable dTPreviewWindow; //modified in thread 

    public DataView dvLbSelection {
            get {
                return dTPreviewWindow.DefaultView;  //DataGridControl binding 
            }
        }

private void LoadDataGridPreview(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

            if (listBoxSelection != null) {
                try {
                    DataTable testImmediateChange = new DataTable();
                    testImmediateChange = DataSetModel.ChunkFlatFile(listBoxSelection, 1, PREVIEW_WINDOW_MAX_ROWS); //labor itensive work 
                    dTPreviewWindow = testImmediateChange;
                    fileOpenGood = true;
                } catch {

                    fileOpenText = DATAGRID_TEXT_BADFILE;
                    fileOpenGood = false;


                }
                fileOpenText = DATAGRID_TEXT_NOFILECHOSEN;

                OnPropertyChanged("FileOpenGood");
                OnPropertyChanged("FileOpenBad");
                OnPropertyChanged("FileOpenText");
                OnPropertyChanged("dvLbSelection");
            } else {
                ValidatePreviewWindow(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what? where is the definition of `LoadDataGridPreview()`?

Comment: @HighCore  I've added that code to the question, but why should it matter?   Why does any control being updated on a new thread alter the interactivity of the views **other** controls?

Comment: There's no such thing as "updating a control on another thread". All WPF elements derive from `DispatcherObject` and can only be manipulated in the UI Thread. Even if you use DataBinding, the `PropertyChanged` notifications must be raised in the UI thread.

Comment: Also, what version of .Net you're using? If 4.0 or newer, you'd better use the TPL instead of the backgroundworker, because it is simpler and requires less code.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataview i.e. dvLbSelection is UI bound, even updating it in the background thread would cause the UI to refresh. And which in turn would cause delays when user is trying to interact with other controls. So here you can try couple of things.

1. Disconnect the dataview from the UI until all data is loaded. (Use temp variable to load the values in background thread)
2. Use Virtualization on the data grid and set the VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Recycling"
3. Avoid creating multiple background threads (as per the provided code snippet, for every ListBox Selection a new thread is getting created). Running expensive operations with many thread would be one of the primary reason for the delays.

Hope this helps!